# creating a (104,1,10) dimensional numpy.ndarray from 10 different (104,) dimensional numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have 10 different (104,) shaped (104 elements in 1 dimension) numpy ndarray. I need to stack all of them together to form a (104,1,10) shaped array. The expected output is like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYtNO.jpg

I had the following code written which of  course is giving me errors as 'rulesetArray' dimension mismatched after first iteration.

valueerror: all input arrays must have the same shape

```py
import numpy as np

rulesetArray=np.zeros((104,1))
listString=['100010001.....','1010101....',,,,,,,,,'100010001.....'] # each element in listString is 104 in length and has 10 elements
for i in listString:
   npArray=np.array(list(i),dtype=int) # outputs (104,) size npArray
   npArray=npArray.reshape(104,1) # converts npArray to (104,1) shape
   rulesetArray= np.stack([rulesetArray,npArray)
```

Comment: `stack(..., axis=1) should produce a (104,10), which can be reshaped to the desired result.   Just do one `stack`, not a repeated one.

Comment: `rulesetArray` starts as (104,1), but what is it after the first `stack`?  (2, 104,1).  You can't stack that with a (104,1)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [116]: alist = [np.arange(10) for _ in range(5)]                                                          
In [117]: arr = np.stack(alist, axis=1)                                                                      
In [118]: arr.shape                                                                                          
Out[118]: (10, 5)
In [119]: arr.reshape(10,1,5)                                                                                
Out[119]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]],

       [[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]],

       [[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]],

       [[7, 7, 7, 7, 7]],

       [[8, 8, 8, 8, 8]],

       [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for `np.dstack()`.

> Stack arrays in sequence depth wise (along third axis). [dstack docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)

Code:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((5, 1))
b = np.ones((5, 1))

print('a:', a, a.shape, 'b:', b, b.shape, sep='\n')

stacked_arr = np.dstack((a, b))

print('stacked:', stacked_arr, stacked_arr.shape, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```py
a:
[[0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]
 [0.]]
(5, 1)
b:
[[1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]]
(5, 1)
stacked:
[[[0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1.]]

 [[0. 1.]]]
(5, 1, 2)
```